# I trying to store my fields in core data it can't store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my code I am using simple registration page. The fields are firstname, surname, email, password, and phoneno. In that if I register a new member means the newly given email id is already stored means it can't store in the core data. This is my condition.

Here is my code,

```
//Appdelegate call

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

//Fetch Request

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSLog(@"Your Request is : %@",request);

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email = %@)", email];

[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error=nil;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"Your Result is: %@",result);


if ([result count] > 0){

    if ([email isEqual:[[result valueForKey:@"email"]lastObject]])
    {
        [alertView AlreadyRegisterAlertView];
    }
    else{

        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSLog(@"Welcome for Register Section");

        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.fname forKey:@"fname"];
        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.surname forKey:@"sname"];
        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.eid forKey:@"email"];
        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.phone forKey:@"phone"];
        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.passd forKey:@"password"];
        [newDevice setValue:nameFile.imgProfile forKey:@"photo"];


        [alertView RegistrationSucessAlertView];

        NSLog(@"Your First Name is: %@",nameFile.fname);
        NSLog(@"Your Sur-Name is: %@",nameFile.surname);
        NSLog(@"Your Email id is: %@",nameFile.eid);
        NSLog(@"Your Phone Number is: %@",nameFile.phone);
        NSLog(@"Your Password is: %@",nameFile.passd);
        NSLog(@"Your Profile Image is: %@", nameFile.imgProfile);
    }

}

// Save the object to persistent store

if (![context save:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

In this code, the condition `if([result count]>0)` is false it means what can I do.

Comment: Check the error value, make sure you don't have nils, verify the spelling, check the database file manually, there might be no records that you expect to see that would mean that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is. What do you need help with?

Comment: hi tom, I need to store five values in core data that I have mentioned above. If your email id is already stored means it don't store in to core data otherwise it store. I am having the problem with my condition, that is if( [result count] >0 ). The result value is given as nil but the result object having some values in database. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is in this line

`NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email = %@)", email];`

The code should have been

`NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == %@", email];`

**Updated:**

First of all, I think the logic is incorrect. You are trying to fetch the core data object before actually saving it. You have to insert new entity and save it to core data. Then you have to fetch for the object for any further processing if needed.
That's why your if condition fails every time.

Comment: Hi Varun, Thanks for your respond but still I can not store the values in core data. It does not check the if condition. Is there any problem with my code means could you change then tell me.  Then tell me how can I delete the core data already stored values?

Comment: Check my updated answer. To delete the core data, just delete the app from simulator/device and run again.

Comment: Thanks Varun. Let I will Check again